# Initialize Model Class Variable At Runtime

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am trying to import student data from an Excel workbook. I have to select `column_name` of the class `StudentMasterResource` dynamically which is present in the file. I got all column name in constants module has one dictionary which name `column_name`. When I do it for the first time, it works, then it fails

**constants.py**

```
column_name = dict()
```

### resource.py

```py
from common_account import constants
from import_export import widgets, fields, resources


def getClassName(key):
        if key in constants.column_name:
            return constants.column_name[key]
        return key


class StudentMasterResource(resources.ModelResource):
    organisation_id = fields.Field(
        column_name=getClassName('organisation_id'),
        attribute='organisation_id', 
        widget=widgets.ForeignKeyWidget(OrganisationMaster, 'organisation_name'),
        saves_null_values=True
    )

    name = fields.Field(
        column_name=getClassName('Name'),
        attribute='name',
        saves_null_values=True,
        widget=widgets.CharWidget()
    )

    date_of_birth = fields.Field(
        column_name=getClassName('date'),
        attribute='date_of_birth',
        saves_null_values=True,
        widget=widgets.DateWidget()
    )
```

**views.py**

```
    from common_account import constants
    from tablib import Dataset
    @api_view(['POST'])
    @permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
    def student_import(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            context_data = dict()
            data_set = Dataset()
            file = request.FILES['myfile']
            extension = file.name.split(".")[-1].lower()
            column_data = request.data
            is_import = column_name['is_import']
            constants.valid_data.clear()
            constants.invalid_data.clear()
        
            if extension == 'csv':
                data = data_set.load(file.read().decode('utf-8'), format=extension)
            else:
                data = data_set.load(file.read(), format=extension)
              
            constants.column_name = { 
              
            'date' : column_data.get('birth'),    
            'name' : column_data.get('name'),
               
            }
            
            if is_import == 'No':
                result = student_resource.import_data(data_set, organisation_id = request.user.organisation_id, 
                offering_id = offering_id,all_invalid_data = False,  dry_run=True, raise_errors=True)
                    
                
                
                context_data['valid_data'] =  constants.valid_data
                context_data['invalid_data'] =  constants.invalid_data
    
                context_data[constants.RESPONSE_RESULT] =  {"Total records":student_resource.total_cnt, 
                                                        "skip records":len(constants.invalid_data),
                                                        "Records imported": len(constants.valid_data),
                                                        }
            
                return JsonResponse(context_data)
             
            elif is_import == 'Yes':
            
                result = student_resource.import_data(data_set, organisation_id = request.user.organisation_id,
                offering_id = offering_id,all_invalid_data = False, dry_run=False, raise_errors=False)  
                context_data[constants.RESPONSE_ERROR] = False
                context_data[constants.RESPONSE_MESSAGE] = 'Data Imported !!!' 
                context_data[constants.RESPONSE_RESULT] =  {"Total records":student_resource.total_cnt, 
                                                            "skip records":len(constants.invalid_data),
                                                            "Records imported": len(constants.valid_data),
                                                            }
    
        return JsonResponse(context_data)
```

Comment: Without seeing the code for `constants`', we can't tell anything.

Comment: @TimRoberts have a look